# Which class fired CollectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, event-handling, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

I have an ObservableCollection which is manipulated by a couple of classes. I want to find out which class fired the event. I already looked at the sender object and went through the properties of the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs but did not find anything. I only get the reason for the event such as: Reset, Add or Remove. What I am looking for is the originator.

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    // if coming from one class do something

    // else if coming from another class do something else
}
```

The purpose of this is that I need my collection to behave in a different way depending on the class that modified it.

Comment: *Why* do you want it to behave differently? There's probably a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: And... [This is what we call the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. If you really need to do that, you can change the type of objects you put in the collection to add some sort of "owner" property, indicating who created them.

Comment: Yeah i already thought of that but I will have to refactor my code quite a bit, it was more of a hope that there would be a way. I was skeptical from the start.